# Display jpeg address as actual images

Tags: python, image, jpeg

Current IDE: Anaconda using App: Spyder.
I wrote a program to data scrape a website and filter posts by keywords.

This is the output.

[image]

What is the best way to display a list of images given jpeg addresses?

A few attempts include: 
    Using Pillows - but the best I can do is open a new tab with Google Chrome to display the photo.
Using Image - but I can only open in Preview saved images on my computer.
Using csv - only to export the output as a neatly formatted csv file.

Comment: Why not use an external app that understands how to read images over HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some regex pattern to match all these cases.

```
import re

if re.search(r'^.*\.jpeg$', full_url):
# do something
```